# Go panics on when having functions declared in code but not called

Tags: go, revel, go-gorm

Context: 
    https://github.com/fusspawn/tserver/blob/master/app/controllers/gorp.go

As part of trying to get gorm setup I tried to convert the standard revel/gorp examples.

However. even having the Begin(),Commit(),Rollback() methods defined is enough to cause go to panic.

```
   TRACE 2015/09/06 17:37:47 harness.go:126: Rebuild                                                                                                  
   INFO  2015/09/06 17:37:47 build.go:172: Cleaning dir tmp                                                                                           
   INFO  2015/09/06 17:37:47 build.go:172: Cleaning dir routes                                                                                        
   INFO  2015/09/06 17:37:47 build.go:172: Cleaning dir tmp                                                                                           
   INFO  2015/09/06 17:37:47 build.go:172: Cleaning dir routes                                                                                        
   TRACE 2015/09/06 17:37:47 build.go:151: Exec: [/usr/bin/git --git-   dir=/home/fusspawn/go/src/github.com/fusspawn/tserver/.git describe --always --   dirty]                                                                                                                                               
   TRACE 2015/09/06 17:37:47 build.go:94: Exec: [/usr/bin/go build -ldflags    -X github.com/fusspawn/tserver/app.APP_VERSION "git-2588ef1" -tags  -o /ho
  me/fusspawn/go/bin/revel.d/github.com/fusspawn/tserver/tserver   github.com/fusspawn/tserver/app/tmp]                                                
   TRACE 2015/09/06 17:39:14 app.go:56: Exec app:   /home/fusspawn/go/bin/revel.d/github.com/fusspawn/tserver/tserver    [/home/fusspawn/go/bin/revel.d/git
   hub.com/fusspawn/tserver/tserver -port=46276 -  importPath=github.com/fusspawn/tserver -runMode=dev]                                                 
   INFO  2015/09/06 17:39:14 revel.go:329: Loaded module static                                                                                       
   INFO  2015/09/06 17:39:14 revel.go:329: Loaded module testrunner                                                                                   
   INFO  2015/09/06 17:39:14 revel.go:206: Initialized Revel v0.12.0 (2015-03-25) for >= go1.3                                                        
   INFO  2015/09/06 17:39:14 main.go:30: Running revel server                                                                                         
   TRACE 2015/09/06 17:39:14 controller.go:402: Registered controller: App                                                                            
   panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Type on zero Value                                                                                           

   goroutine 1 [running]:                                                                                                                             
   runtime.panic(0x88cec0, 0xc21011b7a0)                                                                                                              
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:266 +0xb6                                                                                              
   reflect.Value.Type(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)                                                                                                        
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:1698 +0x79                                                                                            
    github.com/revel/revel.findControllers(0x7f365698bea8, 0x9186e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)                                                                    
    /home/fusspawn/go/src/github.com/revel/revel/controller.go:321 +0x25a                                                                      
    github.com/revel/revel.RegisterController(0x9172a0, 0x0, 0xc2100c4bf0,    0x2, 0x2)                                                                   
     /home/fusspawn/go/src/github.com/revel/revel/controller.go:400 +0x1f3                                                                      
    main.main()                                                                                                                                        
     /home/fusspawn/go/src/github.com/fusspawn/tserver/app/tmp/main.go:150  +0x141b                                                              
     TRACE 2015/09/06 17:39:14 controller.go:402: Registered controller:     GormController                                                                 
     TRACE 2015/09/06 17:39:14 controller.go:402: Registered controller: Static                                                                         
     TRACE 2015/09/06 17:39:14 controller.go:402: Registered controller:  TestRunner
```

Commenting out the method definitions will stop the panic.  I cant seem to understand how not calling these methods (note the revel.InterceptMethod calls are commented out) can make the panic happen :/

Comment: sorry took me a moment to battle the formatting

Comment: Have you tried to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Not only is that *much* easier for potential answerers than looking at a whole GitHub repo (which won't be the same in the future, rendering this post fairly useless) but the act of making an mcve can help the questioner understand their own problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Revel docs, the system looks for Controllers in debug mode by [scanning your source directory](https://revel.github.io/tutorial/requestflow.html#hot-reload) for anything that does an anonymous embedding of a `*Revel.Controller`.  The error your're seeing is due to Revel doing dynamic reflection and screwing up during this controller-scanning initialization.  So now the question is: why is it having trouble scanning for controllers?

Your code appears to try to extend a controller in [EventStream](https://github.com/fusspawn/tserver/blob/2588ef1ee1c0a200576b37ce3548749191d8809c/app/controllers/eventstream.go#L10), which the Revel debug controller-discovery code will try to read as a Controller.  However, the code as it stands is currently violating expectations of the framework by embedding a `*GormController` instead of a `GormController`; see the last part of the [Controllers documentation](https://revel.github.io/quickstart/controllers.html#extending-the-controller).

I think the controller-discovery logic is simply choking because of this.  Fix the `EventStream` structure definition.

If this does correct the issue for you, you should probably send a bug report to the Revel folks, because the error message you're getting back is pretty bad and non-local, because it doesn't mention the name of the thing it's trying to register as a controller when it fails.

Comment: That was it. changing the EventStream docs to embed a GormController and not *GormController stopped the panic. Makes total sense when I think about it. 

Not quite sure how it ended up as *GormController in the first place.